# Как получить модуль без знания его названия в Python-3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я столкнулся с одной проблемой. Задача в том что мне нужно создать такую папку в которой любой человек может закинуть свой модуль где после всего моя программа будет их использовать, но опять же я не могу их импортировать пока так как нет данных о их названиях.

Тогда предположим что я смог хотя бы получить их названия из общей базы данных для этой папки. Но получить я их смог только в определенном списке.

Пример : `mods = ["mod_1", "mod_2", "mod_3"]`

Мне нужно в программе импортировать эти модули, но я не могу и предположить как импортировать модули таким образом

+ По возможности объясните возможно ли импортировать модули из какой-то определённой папки. Просто мне не очень хочется сливать программные модули и пользовательские в одно окружение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама концепции выглядит как что-то потенциально проблемное, опасное и ненадёжное, и я бы посоветовал ещё раз подумать, прежде чем реализовывать что-то подобное.

Но если отвечать именно на тот вопрос, который был задан, то должно работать как-то так:

Сначала вам надо получить список файлов в директории:

```
import os

directory = 'путь к папке'

files = os.listdir(directory)
```

Потом получаем имена файлов без расширения и импортируем их:

```
import importlib

for file in files:
    module_name = file.replace('.py', '')
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

Ну и ещё неплохо бы добавить проверку для каждого файла, что это действительно py-файл, прежде чем пытаться его импортировать, но это уж вы сами.

Comment: Вышла ошибка "ModuleNotFoundError" на одной странице прочитал что ошибка выходит из за не известного модуля. Хотя когда компилятор показывал ошибку то он указал что не найден модуль "hello" который как рас таки и находится в той папке. Значит он смог прочесть его название, но когда импортировал то не нашел. Возможно когда он пытался его найти, то искал в основной папке где и находится этот компилируемый файл. Может можно как то указать откуда надо импортировать модуль в этой строчке? - importlib.import_module(module_name)